# Trying to find all the permutation of a list... trying to get a list of all the permutation, but the list is not what i expected

Tags: python

here's the code :

```
L2 = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
combi_operation = [0, 0, 0, 0]
combi2 = []
for x in L2:
    combi_operation[0] = x
    for y in L2:
        combi_operation[1] = y
        for z in L2:
            combi_operation[2] = z
            for w in L2:
                combi_operation[3] = w
                combi2.append(combi_operation)
```

this is the value of combi2 at the end :

`[['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ['/', '/', '/', '/'], ...]`

when i make a line of code that prints combi_operation like this :

```
combi_operation = [0, 0, 0, 0]
combi2 = []
for x in L2:
    combi_operation[0] = x
    for y in L2:
        combi_operation[1] = y
        for z in L2:
            combi_operation[2] = z
            for w in L2:
                combi_operation[3] = w
                combi2.append(combi_operation)
                print(combi_operation)
```

this is what i get :

```
['+', '+', '+', '+']
['+', '+', '+', '-']
['+', '+', '+', '*']
['+', '+', '+', '/']
['+', '+', '-', '+']
['+', '+', '-', '-']
['+', '+', '-', '*']
['+', '+', '-', '/']
['+', '+', '*', '+']
['+', '+', '*', '-']
['+', '+', '*', '*']
['+', '+', '*', '/']
['+', '+', '/', '+']
['+', '+', '/', '-']
['+', '+', '/', '*']
['+', '+', '/', '/']
['+', '-', '+', '+']
['+', '-', '+', '-']
['+', '-', '+', '*']
['+', '-', '+', '/']
['+', '-', '-', '+']
['+', '-', '-', '-']
['+', '-', '-', '*']
['+', '-', '-', '/']
['+', '-', '*', '+']
['+', '-', '*', '-']
['+', '-', '*', '*']
['+', '-', '*', '/']
['+', '-', '/', '+']
['+', '-', '/', '-']
['+', '-', '/', '*']
['+', '-', '/', '/']
['+', '*', '+', '+']
['+', '*', '+', '-']
['+', '*', '+', '*']
['+', '*', '+', '/']
['+', '*', '-', '+']
['+', '*', '-', '-']
['+', '*', '-', '*']
['+', '*', '-', '/']
['+', '*', '*', '+']
['+', '*', '*', '-']
['+', '*', '*', '*']
['+', '*', '*', '/']
['+', '*', '/', '+']
['+', '*', '/', '-']
['+', '*', '/', '*']
['+', '*', '/', '/']
['+', '/', '+', '+']
['+', '/', '+', '-']
['+', '/', '+', '*']
['+', '/', '+', '/']
['+', '/', '-', '+']
['+', '/', '-', '-']
['+', '/', '-', '*']
['+', '/', '-', '/']
['+', '/', '*', '+']
['+', '/', '*', '-']
['+', '/', '*', '*']
['+', '/', '*', '/']
['+', '/', '/', '+']
['+', '/', '/', '-']
['+', '/', '/', '*']
['+', '/', '/', '/']
['-', '+', '+', '+']
['-', '+', '+', '-']
['-', '+', '+', '*']
['-', '+', '+', '/']
['-', '+', '-', '+']
['-', '+', '-', '-']
['-', '+', '-', '*']
['-', '+', '-', '/']
['-', '+', '*', '+']
['-', '+', '*', '-']
['-', '+', '*', '*']
['-', '+', '*', '/']
['-', '+', '/', '+']
['-', '+', '/', '-']
['-', '+', '/', '*']
['-', '+', '/', '/']
['-', '-', '+', '+']
['-', '-', '+', '-']
['-', '-', '+', '*']
['-', '-', '+', '/']
['-', '-', '-', '+']
['-', '-', '-', '-']
['-', '-', '-', '*']
['-', '-', '-', '/']
['-', '-', '*', '+']
['-', '-', '*', '-']
['-', '-', '*', '*']
['-', '-', '*', '/']
['-', '-', '/', '+']
['-', '-', '/', '-']
['-', '-', '/', '*']
['-', '-', '/', '/']
['-', '*', '+', '+']
['-', '*', '+', '-']
['-', '*', '+', '*']
['-', '*', '+', '/']
['-', '*', '-', '+']
['-', '*', '-', '-']
['-', '*', '-', '*']
['-', '*', '-', '/']
['-', '*', '*', '+']
['-', '*', '*', '-']
['-', '*', '*', '*']
['-', '*', '*', '/']
['-', '*', '/', '+']
['-', '*', '/', '-']
['-', '*', '/', '*']
['-', '*', '/', '/']
['-', '/', '+', '+']
['-', '/', '+', '-']
['-', '/', '+', '*']
['-', '/', '+', '/']
['-', '/', '-', '+']
['-', '/', '-', '-']
['-', '/', '-', '*']
['-', '/', '-', '/']
['-', '/', '*', '+']
['-', '/', '*', '-']
['-', '/', '*', '*']
['-', '/', '*', '/']
['-', '/', '/', '+']
['-', '/', '/', '-']
['-', '/', '/', '*']
['-', '/', '/', '/']
['*', '+', '+', '+']
['*', '+', '+', '-']
['*', '+', '+', '*']
['*', '+', '+', '/']
['*', '+', '-', '+']
['*', '+', '-', '-']
['*', '+', '-', '*']
['*', '+', '-', '/']
['*', '+', '*', '+']
['*', '+', '*', '-']
['*', '+', '*', '*']
['*', '+', '*', '/']
['*', '+', '/', '+']
['*', '+', '/', '-']
['*', '+', '/', '*']
['*', '+', '/', '/']
['*', '-', '+', '+']
['*', '-', '+', '-']
['*', '-', '+', '*']
['*', '-', '+', '/']
['*', '-', '-', '+']
['*', '-', '-', '-']
['*', '-', '-', '*']
['*', '-', '-', '/']
['*', '-', '*', '+']
['*', '-', '*', '-']
['*', '-', '*', '*']
['*', '-', '*', '/']
['*', '-', '/', '+']
['*', '-', '/', '-']
['*', '-', '/', '*']
['*', '-', '/', '/']
['*', '*', '+', '+']
['*', '*', '+', '-']
['*', '*', '+', '*']
['*', '*', '+', '/']
['*', '*', '-', '+']
['*', '*', '-', '-']
['*', '*', '-', '*']
['*', '*', '-', '/']
['*', '*', '*', '+']
['*', '*', '*', '-']
['*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '/']
['*', '*', '/', '+']
['*', '*', '/', '-']
['*', '*', '/', '*']
['*', '*', '/', '/']
['*', '/', '+', '+']
['*', '/', '+', '-']
['*', '/', '+', '*']
['*', '/', '+', '/']
['*', '/', '-', '+']
['*', '/', '-', '-']
['*', '/', '-', '*']
['*', '/', '-', '/']
['*', '/', '*', '+']
['*', '/', '*', '-']
['*', '/', '*', '*']
['*', '/', '*', '/']
['*', '/', '/', '+']
['*', '/', '/', '-']
['*', '/', '/', '*']
['*', '/', '/', '/']
['/', '+', '+', '+']
['/', '+', '+', '-']
['/', '+', '+', '*']
['/', '+', '+', '/']
['/', '+', '-', '+']
['/', '+', '-', '-']
['/', '+', '-', '*']
['/', '+', '-', '/']
['/', '+', '*', '+']
['/', '+', '*', '-']
['/', '+', '*', '*']
['/', '+', '*', '/']
['/', '+', '/', '+']
['/', '+', '/', '-']
['/', '+', '/', '*']
['/', '+', '/', '/']
['/', '-', '+', '+']
['/', '-', '+', '-']
['/', '-', '+', '*']
['/', '-', '+', '/']
['/', '-', '-', '+']
['/', '-', '-', '-']
['/', '-', '-', '*']
['/', '-', '-', '/']
['/', '-', '*', '+']
['/', '-', '*', '-']
['/', '-', '*', '*']
['/', '-', '*', '/']
['/', '-', '/', '+']
['/', '-', '/', '-']
['/', '-', '/', '*']
['/', '-', '/', '/']
['/', '*', '+', '+']
['/', '*', '+', '-']
['/', '*', '+', '*']
['/', '*', '+', '/']
['/', '*', '-', '+']
['/', '*', '-', '-']
['/', '*', '-', '*']
['/', '*', '-', '/']
['/', '*', '*', '+']
['/', '*', '*', '-']
['/', '*', '*', '*']
['/', '*', '*', '/']
['/', '*', '/', '+']
['/', '*', '/', '-']
['/', '*', '/', '*']
['/', '*', '/', '/']
['/', '/', '+', '+']
['/', '/', '+', '-']
['/', '/', '+', '*']
['/', '/', '+', '/']
['/', '/', '-', '+']
['/', '/', '-', '-']
['/', '/', '-', '*']
['/', '/', '-', '/']
['/', '/', '*', '+']
['/', '/', '*', '-']
['/', '/', '*', '*']
['/', '/', '*', '/']
['/', '/', '/', '+']
['/', '/', '/', '-']
['/', '/', '/', '*']
['/', '/', '/', '/']
```

and i'd like to turn that into a list of list...

how do i proceed? thanks!

Comment: okay im editing my post

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new list each time, otherwise you're modifying adding the same list over and over and over. The easiest way to do that is to clone `combi_operation` each time you append it.

```
combi2.append(combi_operation[:])
```

or

```
combi2.append(list(combi_operation))
```

Comment: thanks! it works! although i'm not sure i understand why it works

Comment: in your original code, `combi_append` always points to the same list, when you append it to `combi2`, you just add a reference to the same mutabel list. As you keep changing `combi_operation`, every single item in combi2 will continue changing, because they are actually pointing to just one single list. This answer will fix that, by making a copy of `combi_operation` every time you want to append a new combination to `combi2`. This creates a new list that has no reference to `combi_operation`.

Comment: This is known as mutability. In python, data types such as dictionaries and lists are mutable. https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
L2 = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
combi2 = []
for x in L2:
    for y in L2:
        for z in L2:
            for w in L2:
                combi2.append([x,y,z,w])
```

The problem is that you are always modifying the original list, so it modifies the reference you have in combi2. For lists, python stores the references and not the values.

Comment: You can also use a list comprehension `[[x, y, z, w] for x in L2 for y in L2 for z in L2 for w in L2]`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this in python is to use the [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function.

```
from itertools import product

results = list(product("+-*/", repeat=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the itertools module from the standard library. What you are making looks like cartesian products.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product('+-*/', repeat=4))
[('+', '+', '+', '+'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '-'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '/'),
 ('+', '+', '-', '+'),
 ... 
 ('/', '/', '/', '+'),
 ('/', '/', '/', '-'),
 ('/', '/', '/', '*'),
 ('/', '/', '/', '/')]
```

Itertools also have combinatoric generator for [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [combinations with replacement](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
product('ABCD', repeat=2)                # AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD
permutations('ABCD', 2)                  # AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
combinations('ABCD', 2)                  # AB AC AD BC BD CD
combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2) # AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD
```

Comment: nice! i didn't know there was such a thing, although i'm kind of doing a challenge so im trying to do everything from scratch haha

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for permutations of a list you can go straigth to itertools:

```
import itertools
L2 = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
permutations = list(itertools.permutations(L2)) # the result is casted into a list from a generator
```

Each element of the resulting list is a tuple, but you can easily cast each element with a comprehension expression

```
L3 = [list(element) for element in permutations]
```

Take a look to the documentation for more info on permutations:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: thx! i tried but it doesnt return me list with duplicate item

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`from itertools import product
L2 = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
for i in product(L2, repeat=4):
    print(i)`